# Wireless adapter suddenly not detecting network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, troubleshooting

I've a desktop PC with a wireless adapter stick and a laptop on my table. My phone sitting on the table most of the time as well.

Usually, all three devices are connected to the internet via wifi by the router downstairs. What suddenly happened is that my desktop PC (Windows 8.1 Pro) isn't detecting the wireless network.

Other networks from my neighbors that are in range show up just fine on the desktop PC, just my own isn't. The laptop and phone that are right next to it see it and connect to it just fine and everything works as usual.

I've tried 3 different usb wifi sticks, I've tried a factory reset on the router, I've tried restarting everything multiple times, I've tried reinstalling the wifi stick drivers, nothing changes.

Bridging my laptop's wifi connection via ethernet cable works, but that's just a temporary bandaid.

Googling doesn't turn up anything. No idea where to even begin troubleshooting this.

Comment: Reset your network on your computer and see if it helps. cmd.exe `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /flushdns` then ipconfig /renew` See if you are then able to connect with your adapter.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I tried that, it doesn't work. The command prompt returns "No operation can be performed on WiFi while it has it's media disconnected." The stick is plugged in the entire time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with router settings, I found the solution. Namely, my wireless mode was set to 802.11b+g+n. By changing that to 802.11g+n, my PC is seeing my home network and connects to it without a hitch.

I don't know how or why that helped, but it did, and I'm not gonna look a gift horse in the mouth. Hopefully this answer will help someone else stumbling onto this issue.