# NetGear WNA 3100 doesn't detect my router

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting

I bought NetGear WNA 3100 wireless usb adapter(https://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNA3100.aspx) for my desktop, It was working just fine until I reinstalled my Win7 which made it to work in some funky way. It stopped detecting my main router and only it, if I try using my cellphone as an access point, it sees it and I can browse Internet no problem, it detects the router of my neighbor, although it's further away than mine, which is like in the next room. And the funniest thing it detects my main router no problem if I connect it to my laptop. So the only time it chooses to ignore the main router is when it's connected to my desktop. I tried:

> Downloading newest drivers from NetGear
>
> Connecting adapter to all 6 USB
>
> Reinstalling Win 7 2 times
>
> Resetting both NetGear adapter and main router multiple times
>
> Looking for similar cases in Internet

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: gosh thatś weird... Have you tried moving the placement of your desktop computer? perhaps thereś a large peice of aluminum or something directly between your router and it specifically

Comment: Not possible, it was working before like for 3 months in this very apartment. Unless I became the aluminum. And it detects everything else, like my cellphone, my neighbor's rooter in the house next to mine and the main router as well, when I connect it to laptop.

Comment: And I own 2 NetGear adapters, both work with laptop but not with desktop.

Comment: This case=>http://superuser.com/questions/1065250/wireless-adapter-suddenly-not-detecting-network?rq=1 is surprisingly similar to mine, unfortunately I have no idea where on Sagem F@st 1704 port forwarding page I can change 802.11b+g+n modes.

Answer (score 0):

So, I connected my laptop to my router via LAN cable, and did this:
[image]

Don't ask me how it works, I have no idea. If it helped me it might help you.